# Homeomorphism of two sets in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove or disprove: $$A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x+y \geq 0, xy=0 \}$$ is homeomorphic to $$B=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x+y \geq 0, xy=1 \}$$

$x+y \geq 0$ represents the region above by the line $y=-x$ and together $xy=0$(the axes)

But $B$ represents the same region above by $y=-x$ together with the curve $xy=1$ .But $xy=1$ where $x>0,y>0$ is already covered in  $x+y \geq 0$ so the remaining portion(the other asymptote) is in the third quadrant

Therefore $B$ is not connected whereas $A$ is connected, so they are not homeomorphic

Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried to proof that both $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Since $A$ is an $L$ shape figure, map all points on the $x$ axis of $A$ to the corresponding points on $\Bbb{R}$ and maps the vertical line of $A$ to the negative axes of $\Bbb{R}$ like projection. Is is right for $A$ and $\Bbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $A$ consists of the positive $x$-axis, positive $y$-axis, and the origin.
- $B$ consists of points on the first quadrant that falls on the line $y= \frac1x$.

Guide:

To construct a bijection  continuous map from $B$ to $A$,

$$g(x,y) = \begin{cases}  (0, y-x)&, y \ge x \\ (x-y,0)& x > y\end{cases}$$

Try to construct the corresponding inverse function.

Edit: To find the inverse function for $g$,

Consider the point $(0,y')$, we want to find $(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y)=(0,y')$ where $xy=1$. Hence we have $y-x=y'$ and $xy=1$ which implies $$1-x^2=xy'.$$

We can then solve $x$ using the quadratic formula to obtain the inverse and then find the corresponding $y$.

Your proposed solution is more elegant.

Comment: $f^{-1}(x,0)=\Big(x+1,\frac{1}{x+1} \Big)$ and $f^{-1}(0,y)=\Big(\frac{1}{y+1},y+1 \Big)$. Is this right sir?

Comment: Not quite, but you constructed the inverse function to another function $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} (0, y-1) &, y \ge x \\ (x-1, 0) &, y<x\end{cases}$$ which works and in fact more elegant.

Comment: Thank you sir!.

Answer (score 1):

$x+y \ge 0, xy = 0$ doesn't mean $x + y \ge 0$ *or* $xy = 0$ it means $x + y \ge 0$ *and* $xy = 0$. The set $A$ is the two positive parts of the $x$ and $y$ axes (an 'L' shape).

Similarly, the set $B$ is the portion of the hyperbola $xy = 1$ contained in the set $x + y \ge 0$. Namely, the portion in the first quadrant.

Comment: you mean the negative axes does't include $A$?

Comment: No, because the negative axes don't satisfy $x + y \ge 0$. Both conditions must be satisfied at the same time.

Comment: So,the sets $A$ and $B$ are the same . Am I right?

Comment: No, because $xy = 0$ and $xy = 1$ are different graphs. [These are the two sets](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ufnxhchivc). (I use min(x,y) rather than xy because Desmos doesn't plot one of the axes otherwise).

Comment: sorry sorry ! I understand